# Python: run staticmethod of class in init?

Tags: python, oop

The following is making me suspect whether what I want is a class or a module.

Basically I'm building a parser of sorts, an API library.

The external service which my code connects to needs a token for every time a request is made.

I'm successfully generating this token. However, I'm not sure how I can "give" this token to class instances if it's not in the `__init__` of the class.

My code so far:

```
class MBParser(object):
    pass

class SomeServiceParser(MBParser):

    '''instantiate and use me'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.token = _get_token()


    @staticmethod
    def _get_token():
      # code to get the token
```

Comment: have you read what you posted? It literally makes no sense in English

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I thought this comment was rude until I read my post. I have now fixed the grammar mistakes.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It sees rather ambiguous. I think it's perfectly fine to write `SomeServiceParser._get_token()` and pass not instance to the method by calling on the class object

Comment: @NChauhan I need to make `http` requests in my class methods, these requests require the token, I want to follow DRY by not calling `_get_token()` over and over again.

Comment: I see. You could use a decorator to do this. Ironically I wrote a dummy version of this to explain decorators

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each function that requires a new token in a decorator like the following:

```
def new_token(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.token = SomeParser._get_token()
        r = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I explicitly added a `self` argument in the `wrapper` method since the methods in the class will need this anyway. And this way, I can access the `self.token` attribute and set it to a new value

Could use the decorator as follows:

```
@new_token
def makeHTTPRequest(self, name):
    # ... make request and use self.token here
```